# Card Layout Action Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design, cardlayout

I have created a card layout with four cards.

Sample of my card can be found in the image.[image]
Code for dynamically creating them is below:

```
public class four_future extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters


    public four_future() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
        ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return recyclerView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView picture;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView description;
        public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.four_future, parent, false));
            picture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
            // Adding Snackbar to Action Button inside card
            Button button = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Action is pressed",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });


        }
    }
    /**
     * Adapter to display recycler view.
     */
    public static class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
        // Set numbers of List in RecyclerView.
        private static final int LENGTH = 3
                ;

        private final String[] mPrograms;

        private final Drawable[] mProgramPictures;

        public ContentAdapter(Context context) {
            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            mPrograms = resources.getStringArray(R.array.programs);

            TypedArray a = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.program_picture);
            mProgramPictures = new Drawable[a.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < mProgramPictures.length; i++) {
                mProgramPictures[i] = a.getDrawable(i);
            }
            a.recycle();
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.picture.setImageDrawable(mProgramPictures[position % mProgramPictures.length]);
            holder.name.setText(mPrograms[position % mPrograms.length]);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return LENGTH;
        }
    }
}
```

I have action button in every card. How to open different activities on clicking action buttons on different cards. As of now every action button just gives out a snack bar. If I click action button on first card, it must open first_activity.xml. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `onBindViewHolder` implementation store the information about which Activity to open in the `Button` (you can do something as simple as setting the button's tag with the proper Activity tag, or storing an Intent). Then In the ViewHolder where you do

```
Button button = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_button);
```

you can retrieve the tag and use that to open the proper activity.

EDIT: Try this:

Change your ViewHolder:

```
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView picture;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView description;
        public Button button;
        public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.four_future, parent, false));
            picture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
            // Adding Snackbar to Action Button inside card
            button = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if("activity1".equals(button.getTag()){
                        startActivity1();
                    }else if("activity2".equals(button.getTag()){
                        startActivity2();
                    }else{
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Action is pressed",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

and then modify the `onBindViewHolder` call to set the tag:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.picture.setImageDrawable(mProgramPictures[position % mProgramPictures.length]);
        holder.name.setText(mPrograms[position % mPrograms.length]);
        if(position == 0) holder.button.setTag("activity1");
        else if(position == 1) holder.button.setTag("activity2");
    }
```

Comment: Femi, can you please guide with coding steps on storing information about Activity in Button?

Comment: Femi, thank you very much. Just another favor, I have also created Tile Layout with 6 to 7 tiles. Can point me to tutorial which explains how to add clickable functionality to each and every tile?